# getAmountIn Uniswap/Sushiswap

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, cryptocurrency, uniswap

Im trying to get the price in WETH of 300 COMPOUND and i'm doing it using the getAmountIn uniswap's router function but its giving me a different amout than that from the UI. The expected output for 310 COMPOUND on uniswap its currently 10.4 WETH or 1040... but its giving 1288... (12.8 weth). If you have any suggestion please help me

```
const UniswapCompWethUint = await routerV2.getAmountIn(
    "310",
    ethers.BigNumber.from(response.toJSON().reserve1),
    ethers.BigNumber.from(response.toJSON().reserve0)
); // The output should be 1030 but its giving 1228
```

[310 COMP in WETH on uniswaphere](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6JIU3.png)